# How to escape javascript code in php

Tags: ajax, escaping

I´m working on php to send data to ajax.

```
        $phpArray = array("ok", "
          <script>
        mygallery = [
                        {type: "image", image: "img/gallery/slider/1.jpg", thmb: "img/gallery/slider/thumbs/1.jpg", alt: "", title: "", description: "", titleColor: "#000000", descriptionColor: "#000000"},
        {type: "image", image: "img/gallery/slider/2.jpg", thmb: "img/gallery/slider/thumbs/2.jpg", alt: "", title: "", description: "", titleColor: "#000000", descriptionColor: "#000000"},
</script>"
        );
     echo json_encode($phpArray);
```

How to do the escape properly for this ? I have tried online javascript escape but doesn´t work

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: The problem is I can not get it work because I have ("")

Comment: Just ran this locally and works as expected for me.

Comment: Annnnnnnnnnd now you change the question in it's entirety. Do as you previously had, replace all `"` with `'`, or just escape every `"` with `\"` I just tried both of these solutions and they both work, and print the expected value.

Comment: This is  PHP file. I think yo misunderstood me. I want to send this data to javascript file. As you can see if you have ("") you can not send it unless you have correct backspace to ("")

Comment: I am sorry I wrote it wrong.

Comment: You are JSON encoding it, the output is properly JSON encoded. Your question is unclear, and I am voting to close as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape the " with backslashes:

```
$phpArray = array("ok", "
          <script>
        mygallery = [
                        {type: \"image\", image: \"img/gallery/slider/1.jpg\", thmb: \"img/gallery/slider/thumbs/1.jpg\", alt: \"\", title: \"\", description: \"\", titleColor: \"#000000\", descriptionColor: \"#000000\"},
        {type: \"image\", image: \"img/gallery/slider/2.jpg\", thmb: \"img/gallery/slider/thumbs/2.jpg\", alt: \"\", title: \"\", description: \"\", titleColor: \"#000000\", descriptionColor: \"#000000\"},
</script>"
);
echo json_encode($phpArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. But the script I am using in javascript only accept double quotes

Comment: It actually work !! but I think because I send <script></script> inside data that is why ?

Comment: Yes that changes a lot, looks way different when you do it without, just tested it on my server. But i am happy that it works as needed/wished

Comment: No actually not yet because I have issue with <script></script>

Comment: Oh okay not good^^ so just tell me what it should look like at the end in the sourcecode at the frontend

Comment: When I put this code directly to the index.php it works.
But when I pass it through ajax it doesn´t work.

Comment: AHH sorry i overread that you send it with ajax TO server.. okay i had same/similuar issue on one of my sites.. one moment

Comment: var dataString = YOUR DATA IN ARRAYFORM
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script.php",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
In your PHP:

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));